# Неоднозначная формулировка на главной странице

Tags: дефект, статус-запланировано, локализация

Коллеги, мы недавно поменяли «отвечен» на «опубликован» в нашем интерфейсе. Действительно, говорить, что «ответ отвечен» как-то не выглядит правильно.

Но теперь возникла другая проблема.

[image: опубликован?]

Слово «опубликован» наводит на мысль, что опубликован *вопрос*. На самом деле имеется в виду, однако, что опубликован *ответ*. Возможно, нужно сохранить «отвечен» для этого случая, и оставить «опубликован» для остальных? Или заменить «опубликован» на «ответ опубликован»?

Comment: Там одна строка всего.

Comment: Надо собрать все случаи употребления.

Comment: может "обновление"?

Comment: @Nofate: тогда и под ответом будет написано «обновление»…

Comment: [Тройка: "задан", "изменен", "отвечен"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2447)

Comment: пока поправил на «ответ дан».

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Если она одна, возможно тогда стоит её разделить.

Comment: При необходимости, можно попросить разработчиков разделить строки.